# Disable confirmation for loading file on file changed (MacVim)

Tags: macos, mac, vim, osx-el-capitan, macvim

**This question specifically regards MacVim (for OS X).**

MacVim detects if the file changed on the disk. However, it's asking for confirmation / selection every time:

[image: confirm]

I want it to use `Load File` or `Load All` at all times and skip asking me for confirmation every time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this for the most part with

```
:set autoread
```

From `:h autoread`

```
                 *'autoread'* *'ar'* *'noautoread'* *'noar'*
'autoread' 'ar'     boolean (default off)
            global or local to buffer |global-local|
            {not in Vi}
    When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
    it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
    When the file has been deleted this is not done.  |timestamp|
    If this option has a local value, use this command to switch back to
    using the global value: >
        :set autoread<
```

So this will make it automatically read the changes in *unless you have local modifications*. This is to prevent you from losing work.

If you would like it to autoread regardless of whether or not you have local changes, you could set up an autocommand:

```
autocmd FileChangedShell * e! %
```

However, this will make you very likely to lose work so **I highly recommend not doing this**.